# struts ignores the method and shows no exception

Tags: java, struts

I have a struts method and it was working fine before i added the validation, but once i added the validation method the method which i call is not called and it shows no exception also.

struts-config.xml

```xml
<action path="/RolesAction"  name="SecurEyesForm" type="com.secureyes.eswastha.struts.web.action.RolesAction" scope="request" parameter="method" validate="true" input="/WEB-INF/Masters/RolesMaster.jsp">
  <forward name="rolesHome" path="/WEB-INF/Masters/RolesMaster.jsp"></forward>        
</action>
```

action class :

```
package com.secureyes.eswastha.struts.web.action;

import com.secureyes.eswastha.struts.web.dao.RolesDAO;
import com.secureyes.eswastha.struts.web.viewmodel.RolesViewModel;
import com.secureyes.eswastha.struts.web.viewmodel.UserViewModel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorForm;

public class RolesAction extends SecureyesAction {

    private String forwardRequestTo = "authentication-failed";

    public ActionForward goToHome(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        DynaValidatorForm formObj = (DynaValidatorForm) form;
        int resourceid = 0;
        String pageToken = "";
        boolean isValidMenuRequest = false;
        UserViewModel userVM = new UserViewModel();

        if (request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userDetails") != null) {
            userVM = (UserViewModel) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userDetails");
        }
        if (formObj.get("pagetoken") != null) {
            pageToken = formObj.get("pagetoken").toString();
        }

        if (formObj.get("resourceid") != null) {
            resourceid = Integer.parseInt(formObj.get("resourceid").toString());
        }

        boolean isValidPageToken = isValidPageToken(userVM.getPagetoken(), pageToken);
        if (isValidPageToken) {
            isValidMenuRequest = isValidMenuRequest(resourceid, userVM.getUserRoleid());
            if (isValidMenuRequest) {
                forwardRequestTo = "rolesHome";
            }
        }
        disableAutocompleteFeature(response);
        return mapping.findForward(forwardRequestTo);
    }

    public ActionForward saveRolesDetails(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("save roles");

        DynaValidatorForm formObj = (DynaValidatorForm) form;
        String rolename = "", description = "", functionType = "", roleid = "", saveOrupdateStatus = "", pageToken = "";
        int loggedinuserid = 0;
        UserViewModel userVM = new UserViewModel();
        RolesViewModel dvm = new RolesViewModel();
        RolesDAO rolesDAO = new RolesDAO();

        if (formObj.get("rolename") != null) {
            rolename = formObj.get("rolename").toString();
        }

        if (formObj.get("description") != null) {
            description = formObj.get("description").toString();
        }

        if (formObj.get("functionType") != null) {
            functionType = formObj.get("functionType").toString();
        }

        if (formObj.get("roleid") != null) {
            roleid = formObj.get("roleid").toString();
        }

        if (formObj.get("pagetoken") != null) {
            pageToken = formObj.get("pagetoken").toString();
        }

        if (request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userDetails") != null) {
            userVM = (UserViewModel) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userDetails");
        }

        loggedinuserid = userVM.getUserid();

        boolean isValidPageToken = isValidPageToken(userVM.getPagetoken(), pageToken);
        if (isValidPageToken) {
            if (functionType.equals("add")) {
                dvm.setRolename(rolename);
                dvm.setDescription(description);
                dvm.setUserid(loggedinuserid);
                saveOrupdateStatus = rolesDAO.saveRolesDetails(dvm, functionType);
            } else if (functionType.equals("edit")) {
                dvm.setRoleid(Integer.parseInt(roleid));
                dvm.setRolename(rolename);
                dvm.setDescription(description);
                dvm.setUserid(loggedinuserid);
                saveOrupdateStatus = rolesDAO.saveRolesDetails(dvm, functionType);
            }
            request.setAttribute("message", saveOrupdateStatus);
            forwardRequestTo = "rolesHome";
        }
        return mapping.findForward(forwardRequestTo);
    }

    public ActionForward deleteRoles(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        DynaValidatorForm formObj = (DynaValidatorForm) form;
        String saveOrupdateStatus = "", pageToken = "", roleid = "";
        RolesDAO rolesDAO = new RolesDAO();
        UserViewModel userVM = new UserViewModel();

        if (formObj.get("roleid") != null) {
            roleid = formObj.get("roleid").toString();
        }

        if (formObj.get("pagetoken") != null) {
            pageToken = formObj.get("pagetoken").toString();
        }

        if (request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userDetails") != null) {
            userVM = (UserViewModel) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userDetails");
        }

        boolean isValidPageToken = isValidPageToken(userVM.getPagetoken(), pageToken);
        if (isValidPageToken) {
            saveOrupdateStatus = rolesDAO.deleteRoles(Integer.parseInt(roleid));
            request.setAttribute("message", saveOrupdateStatus);
            forwardRequestTo = "rolesHome";
        }
        return mapping.findForward(forwardRequestTo);
    }

    public List getAutocompleteRolesData(String rolesName) {
        List rolesNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        RolesDAO rolesDAO = new RolesDAO();
        try {
            rolesNameList = rolesDAO.getAutocompleteRolesData(rolesName);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rolesNameList;
    }

    public List getRolesDescriptionAutocompleteData(String rolesDescription) {
        List rolesNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        RolesDAO rolesDAO = new RolesDAO();
        try {
            rolesNameList = rolesDAO.getRolesDescriptionAutocompleteData(rolesDescription);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rolesNameList;
    }

    private String constructRolesSearchQuery(String rolename, String description) {
        StringBuilder rolesSearchQuery = new StringBuilder();
        rolesSearchQuery.append("select roles.rolename,roles.description,roles.roleid from m_roles as roles ");
        if (!rolename.equals("")) {
            rolesSearchQuery.append(" where roles.rolename='").append(rolename).append("' ");
        }
        if (!description.equals("")) {
            if (!rolename.equals("")) {
                rolesSearchQuery.append(" and roles.description='").append(description).append("'");
            } else {
                rolesSearchQuery.append(" where roles.description='").append(description).append("'");
            }
        }
        return rolesSearchQuery.toString();
    }

    public Map getRolesResultHTML(String rolename, String description,HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map roleHTMLMap = new LinkedHashMap();
        String roleQuery = "";
        String path=request.getContextPath();
        roleQuery = constructRolesSearchQuery(rolename, description);
        RolesDAO rolesDAO = new RolesDAO();
        roleHTMLMap = rolesDAO.getRolesResultHTML(roleQuery,path);
        return roleHTMLMap;
    }

    public boolean isRolesExist(String rolename) {
        boolean isRolename = false;
        RolesDAO rolesDAO = new RolesDAO();
        isRolename = rolesDAO.isRolesExist(rolename);
        return isRolename;
    }

    public Map getRoles() {
        Map map = new LinkedHashMap();
        RolesDAO dao = new RolesDAO();
        map = dao.getRoles();
        return map;
    }
}
```

and this is how i call the method :

```
function dataSave() {
                alert("data Save");
                getBlanket('continueDIV');
                document.forms[0].action="RolesAction.htm";
                document.forms[0].method.value="saveRolesDetails";
                document.forms[0].submit();   
            }
```

Comment: ... Not sure what you expect. We don't know what you added. How about you add some logging and see where it's failing?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried to print some message on the console `saveRolesDetails` but the control does not fall there.

Comment: Did you check your JavaScript console for errors? Is your logging at DEBUG so you can see any framework errors? What do you mean by "added validation"? And, SQL injection.

Comment: after adding server side validation = added validations also SQL injection, how to find that

Comment: Then something's wrong with your validation, or it's failing. Re: SQL injection, you're not using prepared statements--you're just building strings without escaping. [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: SQL injection thanks for the info, I will fix this but how to find the other one?

Comment: Fix your validation? See if it goes back to working if you take it back out? Who knows--like I said, we don't know what you added, what changed, anything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19709/discussion-between-anto-and-dave-newton)

Comment: If what you added is `validate="true"` in your config, and the form you submit is invalid, then STruts will directly forward to the `input` JSP. That's how validation works.

Comment: exactly same, the control goes to input page specified with out submitting the form, How to fix this

Comment: By submitting valid data, or by fixing the form's validate method if it returns validation errors when it should not.